# Select multiple table with Linq to Sql

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-mvc-4, linq-to-sql, lambda

I have two tables. There is one-to-many relationship between these tables.I want to select Company table and BankAccount List table (for appropriate CompanyID).
How can I do it with Linq-to-Sql?

```
public class Company
{
    // My Fields
    [Key]
    public Guid ID { get; set; }


    public string FullName { get; set; }

    // My virtual properties FOR relationships(one-to-one,one-to-many etc.).


    public virtual List<BankAccount> BankAccounts { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public class BankAccount
{

    // My Fields
    //[ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    [Key]
    public Guid ID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Companies")]
    public Nullable<Guid> CompanyID { get; set; }

    public string BankName { get; set; }




    // My virtual properties FOR relationships(one-to-one,one-to-many etc.).

    public virtual Company Company { get; set; }
}
```

I write this as follow, but I didn't like it

```
List<List<BankAccount>> bankaccounts = new List<List<BankAccount>>();
foreach (var comp in companyRepository.Companies)
{
      List<BankAccount> banks = new List<BankAccount>();
      foreach (var bank in bankRepository.BankAccounts)
      {
          if (comp.ID == bank.CompanyID)
          {
              banks.Add(bank);
          }
      }
      bankaccounts.Add(banks);
      banks = new List<BankAccount>();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the following will yield the same result.

```
var bankaccounts = companyRepository.Companies.Select(c => c.BankAccounts)
                       .ToList();
```

If you are using entity framework, you can eagerload the 'BankAccounts' property to minimize DB calls.

Hope this helps.